# Android: java TextView Color

Tags: java, android, colors, textview

I need a little help.
I need change the color of a text view with java code..
I tried different way but it always gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried:

```
TextView sts;
sts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stato);
sts.setTextColor(Color.rgb(12,255,0));
```

or..

```
sts.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
```

but both ways 
give me the same error on start..
My Class extends ListActivity

how do I? thanks in advance

FULL CODE:

```
public class ProvaDatabase extends ListActivity{

    TextView sts;   
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        sts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stato);
        sts.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
        //sts.setTextColor(Color.rgb(12,255,0));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        databaseHelper.insertdb(db, "sta", "25/11/2016", "SUCCESS", null, null, null);
        databaseHelper.insertdb(db, "ssis", "25/11/2016", "WAITING", null, null, null);
        databaseHelper.insertdb(db, "AAAAAAAA", "25/11/2016", "FAILED", null, null, null);
        databaseHelper.insertdb(db, "BBBB", "bBBBBBB", "SUCCESS", null, null, null);
        Cursor c = databaseHelper.getDB();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.registryvista, c, new String[]
        { TabellaRegistry.TYPE, TabellaRegistry.DATE, TabellaRegistry.STATUS }, new int[]
        { R.id.tipo, R.id.data, R.id.stato }));


        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
```

Comment: are you inflating your layout, before you fetch textview by id?

Comment: More than likely sts is null when you try to set the color. Are you sure you are setting the content view for the activity you are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your view R.id.stato wasn't found and so *sts == null*. Try check that *sts* is not null, or some your additional code needed

EDIT:

In case when you cannot access layout of your item in list
instead of doing

```
setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.registryvista, c, new String[]
    { TabellaRegistry.TYPE, TabellaRegistry.DATE, TabellaRegistry.STATUS }, new int[]
    { R.id.tipo, R.id.data, R.id.stato }));
```

you can write your own adapter like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    //here goes methods that should be overriden

    //and method getView in which we can access layout of our list item
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = super.getView(postition, convertView, parent);
        TextView sts = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stato);
        sts.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

I hope you got my idea

Comment: R.id.stato is null because it takes data from a database...could this be the problem?

Comment: Some more code needed to know where do you search for this View
Also this would show do you setContentView before setting value of sts, as @dwemthy already mentioned

Comment: put

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);`

at the beginning of onCreate method. sts is not found because content of you activity is not set

Comment: Is this R.id.stato TextView present in your R.layout.main2 layout? May be we should take a look on it

Comment: no, R.id.stato is present in another layout of another xml file

Comment: that is loaded from listadapter

Comment: well, in adapter you defined layout for each item of your list. using findViewById this way you cannot access views in this layout (R.layout.registryvista). Instead you can set color in xml or extend SimpleCursorAdapter and in method `getView` you can inflate your `R.layout.registryvista` and in this layout invoke `findViewByID(R.id.stato)`

Comment: I did not understand very well what I should do..getView not implemented in ListActivity. I tried this: last code in my post

Comment: I updated my answer this the code sample, custom Adapter(it can extend BaseAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter in your case) need to be written to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the content view before you try to get sts? You need to have the content view set in your activity before you can retrieve views from it.